# magento file upload not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have this odd situation. When creating (or updating) a product in the images section whenever I select a file (or multiple files) the list the selected files doesn't appear therefore I can't upload any images to a product. I don't have ANY errors in the console or in the log and the most odd is that when running the code on a localhost it works. All the required folders on the server exists and they are writable. Any ideas on what could be the reason?

Comment: please try with chrome browser

Comment: I've tried several browsers the result is the same

Comment: check the permission

Comment: set media and sub folder of media permission to `777`

Comment: WAF restriction on the server? The Flash uploader on versions previous to a particular version of 1.9 have serious security issues and its operation may have been blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, guys, I found the problem. It easy at it seems took me a lot of time to realize that it's only working when accessing the website with www

Answer (score 0):

Please check Flash browser plugin working. It's should be installed and enabled.